# Increase the speed of drawing lines

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing

So I have a list of Points ordered by some criteria:

```
List<System.Drawing.Point> points = new List<System.Drawing.Point>();
System.Drawing.Point prev = new System.Drawing.Point();
```

and I'm drawing lines between the closest 2 points from that list using

```
prev = points[0];
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch s1 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 1; i < points.Count; i++)
{
    var pp = points[i];
    using (Graphics dr = Graphics.FromImage(img))
    {
        dr.DrawLine(bluePen, prev.X, prev.Y, pp.X, pp.Y);
        prev.X = pp.X;
        prev.Y = pp.Y;
    }
}
s1.Stop();
```

this piece of code takes 2-4 seconds for a 908(width)x297(height) pixels image.

what can I do to improve the speed?

**EDIT:** Posted the final result below. Although the first approach still allows for finer manipulation of the drawing.

```
            using (Graphics dr = Graphics.FromImage(img))
                dr.DrawLines(bluePen, points.ToArray());
```

Comment: Would highly suggest moving your `using` statement outside of your `for`

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:wpf]?

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot +1 to Glorin's comment. You're building and disposing the graphics object every loop iteration - move it outside the for and it should perform better. Andreas' answer is also a good idea too.

Comment: `using (Graphics dr = Graphics.FromImage(img)) dr.DrawLines(bluePen, points.ToArray();`

Comment: @ Glorin Oakenfoot I did that, same result

Answer (score 5):

Try [DrawLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/en-en/library/7ewkcdb3(v=vs.110).aspx) and use an array of points. Then you can do without a for loop.

```
Pen bluePen= new Pen(Brushes.DeepSkyBlue);
Image img = Image.FromFile("my_granny.jpg");
List<System.Drawing.Point> points = new List<System.Drawing.Point>();

// fill points here ...

System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch s1 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
using (Graphics dr = Graphics.FromImage(img))
{
    dr.DrawLines(bluePen, points);
}
s1.Stop();

// do something with your img here
```

Comment: This will not only be faster but also produce __much__ better results for all but the standard pens.. To improve the answer, why not post the corrected code?